# Pasting into Webkit textarea gets capped when body has text-transform: uppercase

Tags: webkit, paste, uppercase

I have...

```
body { text-transform: uppercase; }
```

...and...

```
textarea { text-transform: none !important; }
```

Text pasted into a textarea in Webkit (Safari and Chrome) will get capitalized.
Text pasted into a textarea in Firefox or IE will be left as it was, lower or capped.
I need it to be left alone in all browsers for SQL.

Bug? Fixes?

Comment: I really don't want to remove the text-transform declaration from body and add it to all the individual tags...

Answer (score 1):

You're likely to have a single element wrapping all content or perhaps a small number of them. I've found that the top-most element having text-transform: uppercase does not cause pasted text in WebKit to become upper case.

E.g. instead of:

```
body { text-transform: uppercase; … }
```

Use:

```
body { … }
#header, #content {text-transform: uppercase}
```

Comment: If you paste this code into a new HTML file and open it in Safari, pasted text in the textarea is lowercase? `<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">
body {
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
textarea {
 width: 500px;
 height: 200px;
 text-transform: none !important;
}
</style>

<title></title>

</head>

<body>

 uppercase text<br />
 <br />
 <textarea></textarea>

</body>

</html>`